# How to achieve peer to peer file transfer by WebRTC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, webrtc

I have design a small text based chat system with signalr but I would like to provide a feature to send file from one user end to other user end. Is it possible by WebRTC ?

I got a sample code from [this url](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/filetransfer/), which is probably uploading file from client to server. This [web site](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-rtcdatachannel) has some code for webRTC.

However, I am looking for code which will enable two users to send file to each other with real time file upload progress. So if anyone knows any website which will guide me to do it then please redirect me or discuss with code sample which I need to send file between two users.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible. See https://www.sharedrop.io/

Comment: @jib sharedrop using webrtc which has some problem. webrtc does not support all browser. i am looking for a js library which will go good with signalr and i should be able to send files between two signalr connection or chat users. please suggest possible way. thanks

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23881/send-message-with-signalr-to-clients-from-injected-ioc-method